# can't understand what eval_in_component to do in tcl

Tags: tcl

I don't understand this command

```
eval_in_component [f1 -flag1 $var1] {
                set cell_obj [find_item -type cell -quiet $var]                
                set pin_obj [find_item -type pin "$var/$pin"]
            }
```

What eval_in_component to do ?

Is find_item built in function ? I can't find what to do or its implementation

Answer (score 0):

The commands you ask about (`find_item`, etc.) are not part of Tcl. The commands that are are [listed here](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm).

I did dig further into one of them (`eval_in_component`). It seems to be a command that is specific to some library. Fortunately, I found some [documentation](https://www.scribd.com/document/351711286/coretools-reference-pdf) (though you'll need to search within it) by the “magic of Google” (which you should totally try for yourself). In particular it does the equivalent of this, in modern Tcl syntax (except for hiding the `save_component` variable):

```
set saved_component [get_current_component]
set_current_component $theComponentNameYouSupply
try {
    eval $theScriptYouSupply
} finally {
    set_current_component $saved_component
}
```

The documentation appears to be mushier (it looks like it predates Tcl's standard `try` command) but taking reasonable guesses gives the above.

The exact meaning of `get_current_component` and `set_current_component` is library specific (does the concept of a “current component” make sense to you?) but they would appear to be a matched pair. The pattern is in general a common one; I use something like it for, for example, changing directory to a temporary location just while a particular command is running without needing to be careful about changing back afterwards.